# What is the ordering for `strcmp`'s return value?

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I have a very small amount of code:

```
int test = strcmp("Websecurity", "easily");
printf("%d\n", test);
```

The result is -1. Why? Clearly 'W' is greater than 'e'?

Comment: What makes you think `W` is greater than `e`? If in doubt, you can try printing the numeric values of the characters in question.

Comment: See if your library supports strcmpi() or stricmp().

Comment: I don't see why a misunderstanding requires aggressive downvoting. If this question had been asked 4 years ago, it would have got 100 upvotes.

Comment: Clearly, you have a misconception on how `strcmp()` works.  Unless you identify your codeset as [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) (where `a` to `z` are coded as 0x81..0xA9, with gaps, and `A` to `Z` as 0xC1..0xE9) , your assumption is wrong.

Comment: @BrettHale on one hand, it's not a bad question per se. On the other hand, reading `strcmp`'s documentation again would have been enough.

Comment: @Quentin @BrettHale Thanks!! I did read the `man` pages: http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp . But it did not mention anything about ASCII so it didn't strike me the first time. Putting programming aside, I would have come to the conclusion that lowercase are always before uppercase.

Comment: @codehitman not crystal clear indeed. And [my preferred reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) is not *that* limpid either.

Comment: @BrettHale mouse over the downvote button. "This question does not show any research effort"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of strcmp depends on the encoding of the strings being compared.  Per the Posix standard:

From: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html

> The sign of a non-zero return value shall be determined by the sign of the difference between the values of the first pair of bytes (both interpreted as type unsigned char) that differ in the strings being compared.

In ASCII (and utf-8), capital letters are represented by lower byte values than lower-case letters.  In particular, 'W' is 0x57, and e is 0x65.  Therefore, you are guaranteed a negative return value.

Answer (score 7):

Capital letters come before lowercase letters in ASCII, and so `'W' < 'e'`.

Comment: Strictly, this should be qualified with something like "In most of the common code sets, such as those based on ASCII (which include the ISO 8859-x series of code sets, and Unicode, and many Windows code pages), the capital letters come before the small letters, so `'W' < 'e'` and the return value from `strcmp()` should be negative (the magnitude of the value is not defined)".  But that is applying nuances to an acceptable answer.  Note that [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) is an exception where `a` to `z` are coded as 0x81..0xA9, with gaps, and `A` to `Z` as 0xC1..0xE9.